# Why does the Edit button have a different url then the Edit properties ribbon?

Tags: content-type, view, url, edit

I have a JavaScript that relies on the `contentTypeId` when editing a folder or a document. The problem is when I click on the Edit properties ribbon:

[image: ok]

Everything is all well and good The url:

```
ContentTypeID=0x012000FB1678180F3D3A4088CAFFACD3083D4F0028792A0D16AD0949B9E5835526DB4587&
```

as it manages to get the `contentTypeId` that I wanted.

However when pressing the Edit button from the view:

[image]

The URL won't contain `contentTypeId` and I cannot understand why.

Is there any explanation on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design in SharePoint Library/List.

However you have below two options to edit the document properties:

1. By selecting `Edit Properties` from ribbon.
2. By selecting ellipses(...) after file name in view and then selecting `Properties`.

And If `Edit` button in view is breaking your functionality the you can remove this from list. For this follow below steps:

1. Go to Library.
2. Then Go to Library settings.
3. Select the view you want to change.
4. Un-check the checkbox near `Edit (link to edit item)`.
5. Click `OK`.

Comment: Can I somehow make a custom button instead of the Edit button which points to the Edit properties ribbon?

Comment: Maybe you can try Client Side rendering(CSR)/JSLink option to customize your view. Just a Hint. I don't have ready made code for this.

Comment: Hmm tbh i was thinking of maybe getting the ContentTypeId in another way rather then from the url. i'm fairly new to this so i'm gonna look if i'm able to do this.

Comment: Are you using `ContentTypeId` on `EditForm.aspx` in your custom code?

Comment: Yes, I basically want to check if the folder is a client folder or something else. If it's a client folder i want a button to be visible. This button basically kicks up a workflow which updates permissions for that folder.

Comment: On Edit Form you must be having a dropdown for `Content Type`. From this dropdown you can get the `ContentTypeId` for selected Content type. Try inspecting `Content Type` dropdown, it displays the name of content type. But, it saves `ContentTypeId` as value behind the scene.

Comment: Yep i found it cheers

Comment: Great. Keep using this community to ask your question/doubts.